# Is it possible to enable javascript for a specific URL?

Tags: browser, javascript, url

There are many users who have JavaScript disabled and deny to enable it even for some business applications. Is there any way to allow a user to enable a JavaScript for a specific URL in order to use an application and then to disable again for the rest of URLs? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension to Firefox that does exactly this: http://noscript.net/

Everything is blocked by default, simply add whatever you want to allow and you're good to go.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to find a popular enterprise system which have the ability to enable or disable JavaScript on a site by site bases.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "enterprise system"

Comment: You can use Chrome's advanced settings to disable javascript for a specific site.  Use of wildcards is helpful so you can cover any subdomain or family of domains pretty easily.  https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-enable-or-disable-javascript.

Comment: The rub in some cases is that some pages need javascript to initially load (e.g. sites using AngularJS), but the subsequent AJAX calls and processes are what makes the page a slow dog.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, whilst there are workarounds I think that at then end of the day the techniques involved are so fragmented between different browsers that the answer is "no" you can't.

Ok there is a plugin for firefox but want about Chrome / Safari / Opera ?

Bigbaddonk's answer is a good one however. I can only add that you can set JavaScript to be on/off on a per site basis in Internet Explorer (no plug-in required) by using the security zones feature. The '**Internet**' zone would have JavaScript turned off and you would add the websites you want to have it turned of for by adding them to the '**Trusted Site**' zone. If you are asking this question wearing the hat of an IT Infrastruture administrator them I am pretty sure that you could install the settings required for all your organisation's IE users using a remote rollout. Then the answer to your question would be "yes" but I can't tell where you are coming from.
Otherwise if you are asking because you don't like the fact that users you don't know come to your website and have JavaScript turned off then I'm afraid all you can is inform them that they are missing out because JS is disabled. Use `≤NOSCRIPT≥` tags for this (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) and in the NOSCRIPT you could provide instructions informing them how to turn JavaScript on.